# Entering a level

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am trying to create a level below Ruth & Anita to create one node called 'Chris', with the rest remaining the same as it is currently.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\null\vfill

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%


\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
            -- +(0,-8pt)
            -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
    blank/.style={draw=none},
    level distance=45pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,minimum width=\widthof{Janet Botwood}}]
\Tree [.\node(grands)[rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=2]{Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager \nodepart{second} Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager};  
[ .{Lisa Bradley\\RMN} ] 
[ .{David Craddock\\RMN} ] 
[ .{Tom Cullen\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Jade Faid\\RMLD}  ] 
[ .{Raj Jaganaidoo\\RNLD}  ] 
[ .{Jairus Mabunda\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Anamaria Noaom\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Alicja Pdgorska\\RMN}  ]  ] 
\end{tikzpicture}%

}
\vspace{10 mm}
\captionof{figure}{The Management Structure of Orchard House Nursing Home --     Draft}
  \label{tikz}


\vfill
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}

\null\vfill

\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%


\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
            -- +(0,-8pt)
            -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
    blank/.style={draw=none},
    level distance=45pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={align=center,minimum width=\widthof{Janet Botwood}}]
\Tree [.\node(grands)[rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=2]{Ruth Butler\\Registered Manager \nodepart{second} Anita Kaur\\Registered Manager};  
[ .{Chris} %<-----------------New node
[ .{Lisa Bradley\\RMN} ] 
[ .{David Craddock\\RMN} ] 
[ .{Tom Cullen\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Jade Faid\\RMLD}  ] 
[ .{Raj Jaganaidoo\\RNLD}  ] 
[ .{Jairus Mabunda\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Anamaria Noaom\\RMN}  ] 
[ .{Alicja Pdgorska\\RMN}  ]  ]  ] %<------- Another ]
\end{tikzpicture}%

}
\vspace{10 mm}
\captionof{figure}{The Management Structure of Orchard House Nursing Home --     Draft}
  \label{tikz}


\vfill
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

**Update:**

A doble node on top and below means that the structure you want to draw is not a tree, and although it could be possible to use `tikz-qtree`, `TikZ` or `forest` to trickily draw them, I think a non tree `TikZ` solution could be easier.

Following code shows a solution with several `matrix`, one for each level, and some `foreach` loops which draw connections between nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[person/.style={align=center, text width=\widthof{#1}},
level/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes={person, text align=center}}]
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={person=Registered Manager}] (RM) {{Ruth Butler\\ Registered Manager} & {Janet Botwood\\ Registered Manager}\\};  

\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={person=Something else}, below= 5mm of RM] (Ch) {{Chris\\ Something else}\\};  

\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={person=Anamaria Noaom}, 
below= 5mm of Ch] (RMN) {{Lisa Bradley\\RMN} & 
{David Craddock\\RMN} &
{Tom Cullen\\RMN}  & 
{Jade Faid\\RMLD}  & 
{Raj Jaganaidoo\\RNLD}  &
{Jairus Mabunda\\RMN}  &
{Anamaria Noaom\\RMN}  & 
{Alicja Pdgorska\\RMN}  \\};

\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={person=Janet}, 
below= 5mm of RMN] (BRMN) {{Janet} & 
{Sunny}\\};

\foreach \i in {1,2}
    \draw (RM-1-\i.south)--++(-90:3mm) -| (Ch-1-1.north);

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
    \draw (Ch-1-1.south)--++(-90:3mm) -| (RMN-1-\i.north);

\foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
    \draw (RMN-1-\i.south)--++(-90:3mm) -| (BRMN.north);

\foreach \i in {1,2}
    \draw (BRMN.north) -| (BRMN-1-\i.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]